# Ruby, run all methods

Tags: ruby, methods, symbols

Is it possible to run and output all the methods? Not sure how to pass symbols through the dot operator. So instead of `link.:node` it should be `link.node`

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://stackoverflow.com/")


link = page.link
p meth = link.methods #=> [:node, :href, :attributes, :page, :referer, :click, :dom_id, :dom_class, :pretty_print, :inspect, :rel, :rel?, :noreferrer?, :text, :to_s, :uri, :pretty_print_cycle, :pretty_print_instance_variables, :pretty_print_inspect, :nil?, :===, :=~, :!~, :eql?, :hash, :<=>, :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :initialize_dup, :initialize_clone, :taint, :tainted?, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?, :trust, :freeze, :frozen?, :methods, :singleton_methods, :protected_methods, :private_methods, :public_methods, :instance_variables, :instance_variable_get, :instance_variable_set, :instance_variable_defined?, :instance_of?, :kind_of?, :is_a?, :tap, :send, :public_send, :respond_to?, :respond_to_missing?, :extend, :display, :method, :public_method, :define_singleton_method, :object_id, :to_enum, :enum_for, :pretty_inspect, :==, :equal?, :!, :!=, :instance_eval, :instance_exec, :__send__, :__id__]


   #this doesn't work.
    meth.each do |x|
      puts "#{x}: #{link.x}"
    end
```

Comment: Many of these methods require arguments and can't be called without them.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What are you running the methods on? Also, right now it is outputting a string with just the method name followed by the method passed with no arguments.

Comment: Helps me learn. The methods are symbols, and don't know how to push a symbol into the dot operator.... So instead of passing `link.:node`, it should be `link.node`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to access method of the class, you can use the following ways

To call private methods

```
meth.each { |x| puts "#{x}: #{link.class.send(x)}" }
```

To call public methods

```
meth.each { |x| puts "#{x}: #{link.send(x)}" }
```

To call methods with arguments or params

```
meth.each { |x| puts "#{x}: #{link.class.send(x, params_or_arguments)}" }
meth.each { |x| puts "#{x}: #{link.send(x, params_or_arguments)}" }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `send`, but as pointed out in the comments, a lot of methods will have the wrong arity:

```
meth.each { |x| puts "#{x}: #{link.send(x)}" }
```

BTW: if you are trying to learn Ruby, I wrote a gem that might be interesting for you: [methodfinder](https://github.com/citizen428/methodfinder)

Comment: Hi Micheal.. I answered here for help(KS), not for reputation.. I am not a frequent user of SOF. I can understand that, all are here for rep only. Hope that, I didn't hurt you...

Comment: @Jak Don't worry, I don't care, I found the switch a bit strange since the answers are basically the same. Anyway, I gave you another +1 and will remove the previous comment. Hope we'll see you more active on SO in the future :-)

Comment: Sorry gents, didn't know what to do. New to stack. Jak's answer was more inline with the question, but your answer Michael was better for me, as a person. What would you advise?

Comment: Just keep it as it is :-) When in doubt, I agree with the "in line with the question" argument.